# Authenticate before allowing access to a private Chef Supermarket

Tags: chef-infra

I've created a private chef supermarket server and linked it up with my chef server. I can authenticate and upload cookbooks, however, the domain is public facing. I am unable to find any options in Supermarket to disallow downloading/searching/browsing the site without being logged in.

Is it possible to require login before being able to access a private supermarket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is not supported. You can use HTTP authentication or IP-based restrictions in a proxy server, but in general Supermarket is intended for use in an "anonymous read" situation just like the main site at supermarket.chef.io.